# Android encoding : line feed and carriage return issue

Tags: android, encoding, carriage-return

I experienced an issue in writing a file with android device and carriage return :

```
writer.write((byte)0x0A);
```

Create 2 bytes 0x0D 0x0A in the file (I checked once uploaded to an FTP site).

I tried to create the write with :

```
FileOutputStream writer = parent.openFileOutput(fileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

or

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(parent.openFileOutput(fileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE), "ISO-8859-1");
```

with differents charsets but nothing helped...

On windows and java, this same code run perfeclty with the writer

```
FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
```

And I'm out of ideas to solve this problem...

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: Are you sure it's not the FTP uploader that's doing an end-of-line conversion? The difference between standard Unix EOL (0x0A) and MS-DOS (0x0D0A) has caused a lot of grief for a lot of people when transferring files using protocols like FTP. For example, if you do an ASCII-type transfer from Unix to Windows, most FTP clients will convert 0x0A to 0x0D0A. Use a "binary" transfer option to avoid this.

Comment: Ok, my fault, I was convinced it was my "writing" code... But FTPClient don't make binary transfer by default...

`ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);`

Solved the problem...

Thanks gordonwd for the help and sorry for my stupidity...